# Ubuntu 17.10 and... Display Scale and Brightness issues on nVidia 1060

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

Good morning,
I have an Alienware 13R3 with OLED display at work on Ubuntu 17.10 with the latest version of nVidia drivers.
I have 2 problems for your support:

1. How can I set since the boot the scale resolution of 150%? Now it starts with 200% and it is all to big!!! I cannot also set 150% but just 100% or 200%.
2. How can I set directly the brightness? The control provided doesn't work with the OLED display and thanks to the community I managed that script to run via shell but anything I have to write that (xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --brightness 0.4). How can I run it as root with the first boot or make it persistent?

Thanks!!!